# global variable in javascript strict mode

Tags: javascript, this, global

I keep getting the error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined"

I know its something to do with global variables and scope but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
jQuery(function($) {
"use strict";

var global = this;
var carousel = null;

function mobileOnlySlider(carousel) {

    carousel = $('.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper').slick({

        // normal options...
        infinite: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        dots: true,

    });//slick slider init
}//mobileOnlySlider function


mobileOnlySlider(global.carousel);

    function resetSlick(carousel) {
        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            if ($(window).width() > 768 ) {
                if (carousel.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
                    carousel.slick('unslick');
                }
                else{
                    console.log("returned nothing.");
                    return;
                }
            }
            else {  
                if (carousel.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
                    //do nothing
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    mobileOnlySlider(global.carousel);
                }
            }
        });//window resize
    }//function resetclick

resetSlick(global.carousel);


})();//plain js version of $window ready
```

Comment: did you try removing the `var` when declaring ? 
just write `global = this;
carousel = null;`
then you should be able to access it

Comment: @Dinosan0908 that would be flagged as an error in strict mode.

Comment: There are multiple issues in this piece of code. `global.carousel` is not the same thing as `var carousel = null`. Also the parameter in the functions are also different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redefining a global variable in local scope

```
var carousel = null;

function mobileOnlySlider(carousel) {

    carousel = $('.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper').slick({

        // normal options...
        infinite: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        dots: true,

    });//slick slider init
}//mobileOnlySlider function
```

Within this method, `carousel` is a local variable, not the global one you expect - and when you call it like this:

```
mobileOnlySlider(global.carousel);
```

The global variable is *not* updated.

---

One option is to return the value from that method, and update the variable accordingly

```
var carousel = null;

function mobileOnlySlider() {

    return $('.woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper').slick({

        // normal options...
        infinite: false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        dots: true,

    });//slick slider init
}//mobileOnlySlider function

// elsewhere
carousel = mobileOnlySlider();
```

Comment: So how do I update the global variable? Everything I've tried keeps coming up as undefined.

Comment: @power-of-ra Why not just return it from the method call and update the global variable? See update

Comment: Thank you @Jamiec ! This method worked. I feel stupid now.